# Cannot Update Image In PHP&MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, image

hi guys i am working on a project where i have a student_edit.php file which updates the students
details all my data is updated successfully but there is one problem when i update lets say only two fields and not all then image is blanked and my fields updated successfully.

what i am doing is that i am showing student picture and besides it i have another input fields to browse image to update image. What i want is simple that if i am not updating image instead i update other fields image should be still there and not become blank.

Necessary code snippets is like that:

```
<?php

    $file_name = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
    $tmp_name  = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];

    if (copy($tmp_name, "images/" . $file_name)) {
        $picture = "images/" . $file_name;
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['picture'])) {
        $res = mysql_query("UPDATE student SET `id`='$id',`branch_id`='$branch_id',`class_id`='$class_id',`section_id`='$section_id',`roll_number`='$roll_number',`student_name`='$student_name',`father_name`='$father_name',`dob`='$dob',`student_address`='$student_address',`gender`='$gender',`status`='$status',updated=now() WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        $res = mysql_query("UPDATE student SET `id`='$id',`branch_id`='$branch_id',`class_id`='$class_id',`section_id`='$section_id',`roll_number`='$roll_number',`student_name`='$student_name',`father_name`='$father_name',`dob`='$dob',`student_address`='$student_address',`gender`='$gender',`status`='$status',`picture`='$picture',updated=now() WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    }

?>
```

and their is picture area where i call pics

```
<p>
    <label for="picture"><strong>Picture:</strong> </label>
    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $rec['picture'];?>" width="100" height="100"/></a>
    <input name="picture" type="file" value="">

</p>
```

and their is picture area where i call pics

```
<p>
    <label for="picture"><strong>Picture:</strong> </label>
    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $rec['picture'];?>" width="100" height="100"/></a>
    <input name="picture" type="file" value="">

</p>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess by looking at your code, you are not escaping the value of `$picture` when you place it in the database, which could be why the image value in the database is not updating.

Also, don't use `if(!isset($_POST['picture']))`, but try `if (!isset($_FILES['picture']) || (isset($_FILES['picture']) && $_FILES['picture']['name'] == "")`. The `$_POST` super global won't work, because files are sent via the `$_FILES` super global.

Putting it all together:

```
$file_name = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];

if (!isset($_FILES['picture']) || (isset($_FILES['picture']) && $_FILES['picture']['name'] == "")) {
  $res = mysql_query("UPDATE student SET `id`='$id',`branch_id`='$branch_id',`class_id`='$class_id',`section_id`='$section_id',`roll_number`='$roll_number',`student_name`='$student_name',`father_name`='$father_name',`dob`='$dob',`student_address`='$student_address',`gender`='$gender',`status`='$status',`picture`='$picture',updated=now() WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
} else {
  copy($tmp_name, "images/" . $file_name)

  $picture = mysql_real_escape_string("images/".$file_name);
  $res = mysql_query("UPDATE student SET `id`='$id',`branch_id`='$branch_id',`class_id`='$class_id',`section_id`='$section_id',`roll_number`='$roll_number',`student_name`='$student_name',`father_name`='$father_name',`dob`='$dob',`student_address`='$student_address',`gender`='$gender',`status`='$status',updated=now() WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Also, I REALLY recommend that you use the MySQLi extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

The above code is totally untested, but *should* work.

Comment: thanks for ur rply. i tried ur code but no luck. can u just tell me how can i make this happen if i dont update image field but update other fields then image will not become blank.

Comment: @user1313942 As long as you have defined (and just as importantly escaped) each of the variables within the SQL query, then the query within the `if` statement (not inside the `else`) should do the trick

Comment: i tried every thing which i know but i cant get it right anybody else rply is appreciated.